# sharepoint 2013 filter a view like [me] for groups

Tags: document-library, permissions, list-view

I got some document libraries that requires some additional filtering.
At first i filtered on [Me] but that requires the people to be added by name.
Eventually i like to add people by groups, ea sales marketing management.

As [Me] Doesn't seam to work in those situations.

Comment: How many groups you have?

Comment: I think eventually around 12 groups maybe a few more or less.
But for another situation i might require a lot of groups, not sure about that yet.

Comment: [Me] only compares on account name, it does not drill down into membershipgroups

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this out of the box.

Work arounds I can think of

1. Create views for each group
2. Create a page and add those views into the page as web part.
3. Audience target each web part to each group. This will hide web part current user is not part of.

Disadvantage is if user is part of more than one group then user will see multiple views on the page.

Another option is to use unique permission on list items.

Another option you can try is to use CAML `Membership` element.

Comment: the multiple membership would then be problem, using permmissions would require my users to learn permission, and set it (as an additional step)

Comment: You could do it with Client Side Rendering; Hide the items on first display, in the OnPostRender code of CSR check the current users permissions against each item (multiple select Choice field matching SP Groups). It requires some advanced scripting.

Comment: A related question that was asked today: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179467/how-to-get-group-name-to-which-user-belongs

Comment: @DannyEngelmanNVP instead of CSR I think updating the CAML query of list view web-part will be much easier.

Comment: Yes, depends on the use-case, we have a UX that shows all the documents your groups have access to, and a drill down filter to filter on one/more group (The UX is a 1:1 implementation of the [Isotope Filter](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html). With CAML you would have to do a round-trip to the server again and again.

Comment: use case a document library view where i filter a person/group column on [Me]  (and get results of groups where i as a person belong to)